How to disable Tx line of USB to Serial converter?
I have a working system where using a CH340 based  USB to Serial converter I am sending data over UART to an ATMEGA16 microcontroller at a baud rate of 9600. Now I am trying to implement an other device with an STM32 nucleo development board, that sends some other data through UART to the ATMEGA16 (using a level shifting circuit). Additionally, I wish to keep the functionality of the CH340.
Now when the stm32 is connected to the Tx line (with the CH340 unpowered), the Tx line is not functional because of whatever is going on inside the CH340. This can be solved using a simple switch, but I would like to avoid having to flip one when I plug in the stm32 board. So the behaviour that I wish to achieve is the following:

When the stm32 is unpowered (with ST-LINK disconnected), the CH340's Tx line should be connected to the Rx pin of the ATMEGA16.
When the stm32 board is powered the CH340's Tx line should be "disconnected" from the Rx pin and the stm32's Tx pin should be connected to it, regardless of whether the CH340 is powered or not.
Another restriction is that I do not want to source any power from the CH340's 5V line.

Now this feels like a task that can be solved with MOSFETs and I have already started playing around with simulations and I came up with this circuit (picture below):
https://tinyurl.com/24yw67lt
My understanding of this circuit is the following:

When power is off, Q6 pulls down the gates of Q4 and Q5 (because of R5), therefore they turn on and conduct (one through the body diode, the other through being turned on and providing a low R_on conduction path, depending on the CH340_Tx voltage). In this state if CH340_Tx is high, R1 pulls up the gate of Q1, turning it "off", so that basically no current flows into the Tx pin of the stm32 while it is powered off.

When power is on, Q6 no longer pulls down the gates of Q4 and Q5, if CH340_Tx is high, then Q5 does not conduct (because Q4's body diode conducts and R3 pulls up the voltage on the gate of Q5), if it is low, then Q4 does not conduct. All the while Q3 pulls down the gates of Q1 and Q2, therefore allows for the stm32_Tx line to control the voltage on com_out_Tx (which would then be connected to the Rx pin of the ATMEGA16).

R2 and R4 are there to discharge the gate capacitance of the MOSFETs when pulling either Tx line low from high.


Now as far as I know the Rx (PD0) pin of the ATMEGA16 is a high impedance input pin, therefore I don't need to worry about a voltage being sustained on the Rx line of the ATMEGA that would send a continuous high current through the low impedance path of the P-MOSFETs in either power state.
My questions are the following:

Is my understanding of the circuit correct?
Does this have a chance of working?
Is this a sensible way to achieve this or is there a much simpler way?
Since I'm dealing with relatively low frequency communication, basically any logic level MOSFET will do, right?
Am I right in thinking that the Rx line of the CH340 should also be treated with the same logic since god knows what the CH340 does to it when unpowered? Maybe in the Rx case this could be simplified?
Any recommendations toward the values of the resistors R1 and R3? Are R2 and R4 unnecessary?

Any help and input is appreciated!


Calls for a mux IC: these can be had for cents and can be used to control which lines get connected without your discrete FET circuitry.
The 74LVC1G157 (e.g. Nexperia implementation) is "the" classic single-bit 1:2 mux. Every distributor has variants of such ICs in mass, e.g. digikey.
Analog switch ICs would work as well, and potentially even easier, because as long as the control voltage selecting the active input is sufficient, the input voltage will simply be reached through to the output.

The problem with using a logic IC like the 74LVC1G157 is that it requires external power for switching. I would like to avoid using the CH340's power line if possible and when the stm32 board is unpowered I have no way of connecting the Tx line of the Ch340 to the Rx pin.

Your Atmel is powered anyways. So use its power supply.

Very true, but I also would like to avoid using its power because of spatial considerations.

I don't understand these spatial considerations – you are running signal lines to that IC, so you have to have at least the signal lines and a reference ground level, otherwise you'd not be getting reliable communications. Is adding a fourth line for VCC really a problem?

You and @Justme may be right, it might just be much simpler to add the VCC line, thanks.

Also, follow up question: how would you go about powering the IC? I mean that the VCC of the Ch340 can not be the single source of power because I also want to power the IC when only the stm32 is powered. Connecting the VCC of the Ch340 to the 5V of the nucleo board surely isn't a good idea?

I don't know the rest of your power architecture, you'd have to ask a new question post and describe that in more detail

You seem to have an XY problem. You have a simple problem X, but have decided to solve in a way Y that raises even more questions and problems than if you just had asked about solving the original problem X.

Is your understanding about the circuit correct: You have drawn it in a simulator so you can verify if it works like you expect or not.

Does it have a chance of working : it does, maybe eventually after tweaking, but out of the box, unlikely it will work in a way that is satisfactory to what you want to achieve

No it is not sensible and yes there is a simpler way. Use ICs instead of discrete resitors and FETs. ICs like multiplexers and level shifters exist.

You are actually dealing with rather high speed digital signals. It's the edges of the 9600 bps signal that are fast. The 9600 bps just limits the time between the fast edges. The edges out of MCUs are so fast they are capable of tens if not hundreds of MHz. Compare it with empty highway with one car passing every minute really fast so passing of a car takes a blink of an eye, instead of having a lot of cars stuck in a city traffic jam going really slowly where passing of a car takes a few seconds.

Maybe, but you really should not be sending signals from TX output pins of RX pins of unpowered chips as then thet are no longer unpowered and can work errarically when powered via data pins. It is best to also level shift with a buffer that allows being unpowered between unpowered CH340 and powered Mega16.

No recommendation to the resistors as I've already suggested to forget discrete FETs and use a better solution with ICs that buffer and level shift and allow connections between powered and unpowered chips.


Genrally you would design a system so that it is safe, by either keeping all chips powered, or with circuitry between powered and unpowered parts to meet their proper usage conditions.

Thank you for the detailed answer, my goal with this circuit was to inject the stm32 into the system with the smallest possible modifications to the whole system. Regarding the digital signal speeds: in this case wouldn't you need to only consider the switching speed of the MOSFETs (ignoring the ringing that may occur due to the edges)?
